# Word used to designate a group of sub-terms

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Example:

I have the words red, blue, yellow, green.
The term enclosing all those words would be "color".

For computer, phone, laptop, that word may be electronic devices.

On top of most words, you have the word "thing".

In short, what do you call a word enclosing a specific group of words?

Right now, I am searching for a word enclosing words such as "beehive", "birdbox", and other spaces humans created for animals to live in, most often as a product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word for a superset is *hypernym*.

> hypernym: A word with a broad meaning constituting a category into which words with more specific meanings fall; a superordinate. For example, colour is a hypernym of red.
>   [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hypernym)]

Comment: This has been asked and answered more than once on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, I'm sorry. I did search before asking, but I did not find that question - May be because my way of designating that word was different than the one from that question.